# Mach-O - LINKEDIT section endianness

Tags: macos, binary, reverse-engineering, darwin, mach-o

I'm a little confused on the `__LINKEDIT` section.

Let me set the background:

### What I understand about `__LINKEDIT`

In theory (http://www.newosxbook.com/articles/DYLD.html) the first "section" will be `LC_DYLD_INFO`.

If I check `mach-o/loader.h` I get:

```
#define LC_DYLD_INFO    0x22
...
struct dyld_info_command {
   uint32_t   cmd;              /* LC_DYLD_INFO or LC_DYLD_INFO_ONLY */
   uint32_t   cmdsize;          /* sizeof(struct dyld_info_command) */
...
```

If I check a mach-o file with `otool` I get:

```sh
$ otool -l MyBinary  | grep -B3 -A8 LINKEDIT                                                              
Load command 3
      cmd LC_SEGMENT_64
  cmdsize 72
  segname __LINKEDIT
   vmaddr 0x0000000100038000
   vmsize 0x0000000000040000
  fileoff 229376
 filesize 254720
  maxprot 0x00000001
 initprot 0x00000001
   nsects 0
    flags 0x0
```

If I check the hex using `xxd`

```sh
$ xxd -s 229376 -l 4 MyBinary
00038000: 1122 9002                                ."..
```

I know that the endiannes of my binary is `little`:

```sh
$ rabin2 -I MyBinary                                                                                        (03/14 10:21:51)
arch     arm
baddr    0x100000000
binsz    484096
bintype  mach0
bits     64
canary   false
class    MACH064
crypto   false
endian   little
havecode true
intrp    /usr/lib/dyld
laddr    0x0
lang     swift
linenum  false
lsyms    false
machine  all
maxopsz  16
minopsz  1
nx       false
os       darwin
pcalign  0
pic      true
relocs   false
sanitiz  false
static   false
stripped true
subsys   darwin
va       true
```

I can corroborate that the first section in `__LINKEDIT` is `LC_DYLD_INFO` by getting it's offset form `otool`:

```sh
$ otool -l MyBinary  | grep -B1 -A11 LC_DYLD_INFO                                                          (03/14 10:25:35)
Load command 4
            cmd LC_DYLD_INFO_ONLY
        cmdsize 48
     rebase_off 229376
    rebase_size 976
       bind_off 230352
      bind_size 3616
  weak_bind_off 0
 weak_bind_size 0
  lazy_bind_off 233968
 lazy_bind_size 6568
     export_off 240536
    export_size 9744
```

If we check the offset of `__LINKEDIT` and from `LC_DYLD_INFO` we get the same: `229376`

Everything fine at the moment, kinda make sense.

## My confusion

Now when I'm in `lldb` and want to make sense of the memory.

I can read the memory at the offset:

```
(lldb) image dump sections MyBinary
...
 0x00000400 container        [0x0000000100ca0000-0x0000000100ce0000)  r--  0x00038000 0x0003e300 0x00000000 MyBinary.__LINKEDIT
```

Ok, let's read that memory:

```
(lldb) x/x 0x00000100ca0000
0x100ca0000: 0x02902211
```

So this is my problem:

`0x02902211`

Let's assume I don't know if it's Little or Big Endian. I should find `0x22` at the begining or at the end of the bytes. but it's in the middle? (This confuses me)

the `0x11` I guess is the size `17`(in decimal) which might corresponds to what I can see from the structure in `loader.h` (12bytes + 5bytes of padding?) :

```c
struct dyld_info_command {
   uint32_t   cmd;              /* LC_DYLD_INFO or LC_DYLD_INFO_ONLY */
   uint32_t   cmdsize;          /* sizeof(struct dyld_info_command) */

    uint32_t   rebase_off;      /* file offset to rebase info  */
    uint32_t   rebase_size;     /* size of rebase info   */

    uint32_t   bind_off;        /* file offset to binding info   */
    uint32_t   bind_size;       /* size of binding info  */

    uint32_t   weak_bind_off;   /* file offset to weak binding info   */
    uint32_t   weak_bind_size;  /* size of weak binding info  */

    uint32_t   lazy_bind_off;   /* file offset to lazy binding info */
    uint32_t   lazy_bind_size;  /* size of lazy binding infs */

    uint32_t   export_off;      /* file offset to lazy binding info */
    uint32_t   export_size;     /* size of lazy binding infs */
};
```

## My questions

1.) Why is the `0x22` not in the end(or beginnig)? or am I reading the offset incorrectly?
2.) `otool` says that the command size is `48` (that's `0x30` in hex) but I can't get it from the bytes next to `0x22`. Where do I get the size from?

Thanks for taking the time to read all the way here, and thanks for any help.

Comment: You expect the `dyld_info_command` to be inside the linkedit segment, which it is not. It's in the Mach-O header, and the fields in it point to areas inside the linkedit segment. Also, the command ID is 32 bits, so you'd expect either `00 00 00 22` or `22 00 00 00`.

Comment: Perfect! thanks @Siguza, that makes sense. I found the Load Command I was searching for in the header, and managed to get the offset from there.